# Unable to access JBOSS server deployed on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jboss, amazon-ec2

I have deployed jboss-4.2.3 on an EC2 instance. I have added appropriate rule to open port 8080 for inbound traffic. When I ssh into this instance and do curl localhost:8080, the expected response can be seen

But when I try to access it in a browser on my laptop, am unable to connect. Few other things I have tried to eliminate other possibilities

1. In order to eliminate possibility of firewall issues on my laptop, have tried to connect from another instance on amazon. Doesnt work
2. Also tried to configure jboss to listen to port 80. Still it can't be accessed. Apache running on port 80 however responds

Any guidance is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind your jboss to all IP addresses as below:

```
./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Aah ..missed that step. Thank you :)

Comment: @slayedbylucifer: Thank you so muchhh. I had the same problem now it resolved.but when i m binding it to my public ip why it is not accessble, can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue.

You need to open up port 8080 in the *Security Groups* as Wildfly is using it. Then you should be able to access the page.

[image]